# Delphi7. How to unload dll without app restarting?

Tags: delphi, dll

I need to replace my dll without restarting of app, but after FreeLibrary it is still used and cannot be deleted.

Please help.

```
//...
function MyFunc(): PChar; stdcall; external 'MyDll.dll';

implementation

//...

hDLL := LoadLibrary('MyLib.dll');
if hDLL = 0 then
  Begin
    LogError('Can''t load MyLib.dll!');
    exit;
  end;

try
  MyFunc();
finally
  FreeLibrary(hDLL);
end;

if not DeleteFile('MyLib.dll') then
  LogError('Can''t delete MyLib.dll!');
```

Comment: I don't think you can. You can simply install the new DLL with a different name, link to that and, on a restart, let the old DLL be deleted and the new one be renamed.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Wrong. When you call `FreeLibrary`, if the reference count goes to 0 then the DLL us unloaded. So long as no other process has loaded it, it can be deleted.

Comment: @David: But obviously it can't be unloaded. So whatever the cause, I would do things as described.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Personally, I like to understand things rather than sweep them under the carpet. Anyway, the main point is that your comment is factually wrong. I'm glad we've cleared that up.

Comment: I've been doing it for ages with [xxm](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/blob/master/Delphi/common/xxmPReg.pas#L195) without much trouble.

Comment: @David: "we" haven't cleared anything up. My comments are factually not wrong, because *obviously*, the DLL can't be replaced or unloaded. Something is hanging on to it, and no matter what it is, my method would be a solution.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Your comment is indeed factually wrong. It's trivial to see that after `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary`, the file can be deleted.

Comment: @David: obviously it couldn't be deleted, see question. So no, my comment is not factually wrong. Obviously something else is stopping it from being deleted, but what that is doesn't matter. Fact is it can not be deleted.

Comment: @rudy Stop being so silly and stubborn. Clearly something else is stopping it being deleted. But it's nothing that can be seen in the question. Your comment implied that once a dll was loaded into a process, that file could not be deleted until that process terminates. We all make mistakes. You've learnt that a dll can be loaded and unloaded, and then deleted. You should be happy with your new knowledge. You should not be trying to deny it!

Comment: @David: "Clearly something else is stopping it being deleted". Exactly. So, when it can't be deleted, at least not when the app is running, to replace the DLL, one must do something else. My comment certainly did not imply what you think it did. And I know, because I wrote it.

Comment: @David: and stop being so patronizing. You mistook my comment and now think you taught me something. What is wrong with you?

Comment: @Rudy You said that "it can't be done" in reference to the code in the question. You are wrong. You are right though in one point, you've learnt nothing. Oh well.

Comment: Stop telling me how I should interpret my own comment. I just said it can't (obviously) be done. The question said it couldn't be done. So I gave an alternative. Not as answer, but as comment, as an answer would have required more effort. This entire silly idiotic comment discussion with you cost me too much time already. What is wrong with you and why do you like to be so nitpicky, and misinterpret what I write, not for the first time?

Comment: @Rudy It can be done. Trivially. So what you said was wrong. You won't learn.

Comment: No, it wasn't. As the question says: it can not be deleted.

Comment: @Rudy You are wrong. As is the asker. Surely you know that LoadLibrary, and then FreeLibrary releases the lock on the file allowing it to be deleted.

Comment: Yes, I know, so, as you said in your "answer", something else is stopping it from being deleted. Well, that is all I said. Which part of that didn't you understand or misinterpret?

Comment: @Rudy That's not what is written. Perhaps you meant something else. I can't imagine what though.

Comment: What is written: "but after FreeLibrary it is still used and cannot be deleted." Well, indeed. In other words, something is stopping it from being deleted. Well, no matter what it is that is still using it, it can obviously not be deleted. How hard is it to understand that?

Comment: @Rudy Your comment implies clearly that what the asker is trying to do can't be done. It can. Once the rogue references to the module are found and removed.

Comment: Yes, that is what I write: it is obvious from the question that what the asker is trying to do can't be done (otherwise there would not be a question). Because obviously, something **external** to the program seems to stop it from being deleted. As you already noted, it can't be the balanced loading/unloading **in** the program.

Comment: @Rudy Your comment makes no sense at all to me then. Question says "X happens, how can I avoid it". You say, "if you change nothing, you can't avoid it." Seems nugatory. Anyway, I can only assume that's what you meant, if you say so. As I said, I personally prefer to understand rather than to sweep under the carpet as you suggest.

Comment: @David: I know what I wrote. It can still be seen above. I did not write "if you change nothing". It is obviously an external program stopping the deletion. The program itself can't avoid that.

Comment: @Rudy Not necessarily. My answer lists a number of other possibilities.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis This might be the point for you to reconsider your stance .......

Comment: M stance was: "I don't think you can". I can't reconsider that, because I didn't think (s)he could <shrug>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, let's clear up a very common mistake. You write:

```
if hDLL < 32 then
```

This is **not** how to test for failure when loading a DLL. As stated very clearly in the documentation for `LoadLibrary`, failure is indicated by a return value of `NULL`, which in Delphi terms is `0`. So you should replace that test with:

```
if hDLL = 0 then
```

Beyond that, so long as each call to `LoadLibrary` is paired with a matching call to `FreeLibrary`, then it is possible to delete the file.

So, something else is stopping you from deleting it. For instance that might be:

- The DLL is located in a directory where your user does not have rights to delete it.
- Another process has loaded the DLL.
- Your process has loaded the DLL by some other means and therefore still holds a reference to it.
- The DLL is not located in the current working directory. Because you used a relative path, the DLL search path is used when you load the DLL, but the working directory is used when you attempt to delete it. These might not coincide.

Note that this list is not exhaustive.

You need to do some debugging now. You are faced with a situation where a call to `DeleteFile` fails. So, ask the system why.

```
if not DeleteFile('MyLib.dll') then
  LogError(Format('Can''t delete MyLib.dll, error code = %d', [GetLastError]));
```

Comment: Even more, I can not delete MyLib.dll even before the LoadLibrary called. If I comment out declarations of all the functions that are used from the dll, then the file is deleted.

Comment: My answer lists various reasons why that might be so. You need to do some debugging to find out which it is.

Comment: I think, your answers list is not complete. My exe cannot be started without dll. So how it can be deleted after start? I think @RudyVelthuis was not wrong.

Comment: Hang on. You are telling me that your executable links implicitly to the dll? That's item 3 in my list. If that is the case then you would need to switch to explicit linking for this dll. But you'd also need to make sure that you severed all links when you unloaded.

Comment: It might help you to build a very simple example. A simple gui app and a dll which doesn't even export a function. Have the GUI program load the dll with LoadLibrary. Then try to delete the dll. Then unload with FreeLibrary. Then try to delete.

Comment: yes, you are right, the problem was in implicit linking. I changed my code to explicit linking and now it works! Thanks so much!